# Adding YouTube video to product and CMS pages Magento

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, module, content-management-system

I've created a custom attribute in my Magento store in order to show youtube videos by adding the video id in to a text field.

I've placed this code in `video.phtml` which is in `catalog/product/view` folder

```
<p>
<?php $attStuff= $_product->getData(); ?>
<?php if( !empty( $attStuff['videoid'] ) ): ?>
<iframe width="330" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $attStuff['videoid']; ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

I now wish to have the video show in the right sidebar of a CMS page and have added a layout update referencing `video.phtml`:

```
 <reference name="right"> 
 <block type="core/template" name="catalog.product.video"   template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml" /> 
  </reference>
```

I now get the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/design/frontend/bootstrapped/default/template/catalog/product/view/video.phtml on line 13

and I can't diagnose the problem!

Any ideas as to what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close. Instead of setting the block type to be `core/template`, you need to use a class that has the ability to check the current product. The `catalog/product_abstract` block has those very functions. Do this for your layout file:

```
<reference name="right"> 
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="catalog.product.video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml" /> 
</reference>
```

Then, in your video file:

```
<p>
    <?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
    <?php if($_product->getVideoid()): ?>
    <iframe width="330" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideoid(); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <?php endif; ?>
</p>
```

---

**Edit:**

If you are using it on CMS pages, that becomes a little more challenging. You need to determine what product you want to retrieve the video for. There are a number of ways of doing this. If you are using a layout update in the CMS page, you could do something like this:

```
<reference name="right"> 
    <block type="catalog/product_view" name="catalog.product.video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml">
        <action method="setProductSku"><sku>sku-here</sku></action>
    </block> 
</reference>
```

And then, in your video file:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductSku(), 'sku'); ?>
<?php if ($_product->getId() && $_product->getVideoid()): ?>
<p>
    <iframe width="330" height="253" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $_product->getVideoid(); ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</p>
<?php endif;?>
```

I am suggesting this method, because it doesn't sound as if you are very familiar with creating your own module. I would highly recommend looking that up, because what I am showing you here is not best practice, ie loading a model in a block template file. It should be moved into it's own block class (which could extend `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract`, and override the `getProduct()` method).

---

**Edit #2:**

The product ID can be used. In the layout xml, change the

```
<block type="core/template" name="catalog.product.video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml">
    <action method="setProductId"><id>id-here</id></action>
</block>
```

In the template code, use this line:

```
<?php $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId()); ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Made the changes but Magento didn't like it `Fatal error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 491`

Comment: Oops. My bad - I apologize. I have changed the block reference to `catalog/product_view`. Please remember to accept the answer if it works.

Comment: This actually works in product view pages with no errors but in a CMS page there is a problem. I still get an error after making the changes: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 56`

Comment: Thank you could I use productId instead of SKU?

Comment: I think I do need to create a module for this to work in a CMS page. I still get an error after making changes to the code: `Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysite/app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 56` i will need to create a module for this to work. Actually need to write two ASAP

Comment: Yep - I just updated. I forgot that we don't need the `catalog/product_view` block anymore.

Comment: I used the code from your above post adding the productId to the layout xml file and it worked - Thanks DUDE!